# What's the difference between using "e" and "E" in a floating point constant?

Tags: c, syntax

When using a floating point constant in C, what's the difference between using *E* and *e* (or *G* and *g*, for that matter)?

For example, what's the difference between
`1.575E1` and `1.575e1`?

Isn't C supposed to be a case-sensitive language? If there's no difference between using *E* and *e*, why's that?

I've looked it up online and on the textbook I'm using and haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: There's no difference whatsoever.  And, yes, C is usually case-sensitive, but I guess you can think of this as an exception.  It's not unprecedented, though: after all, `0xabc`, `0xABC`, and `0Xabc` are all acceptable hexadecimal constants.

Comment: Similarly `long long var = 2Ll;` is valid – not even consistent use.

Comment: @SteveSummit: If there is no difference, how come we can tell them apart?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Actually, no — the valid suffixes for `long long` are `ll` and `LL` but not the mixed case variant.  See C11 [§6.4.1.1 Integer constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1).  Even without any warning options, GCC doesn't accept the mixed-case suffix.  However, you can use `unsigned long long var = 2LLu;` since the `LL` is one suffix and the `u` is a second suffix, but the individual suffixes must be self-consistent in letter case.  I firmly believe that the suffixes should always be written in all upper-case, if only because `l` and `1` are often hard to tell apart.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wrote that after checking with a MSVC compilation, though laxity doesn't prove anything. I do try to avoid using `l` (ell) at all, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference. `1.575E1` is the same as `1.575e1`.

Just like there is no difference between `0xa` and `0xA`—they are both equal to `10`, and have the same type.

In C, identifiers are case-sensitive. Identifiers are names of functions, types, variables, etc.

Comment: C 2018 6.4.4.2 5 says “… All floating constants of the same source form shall convert to the same internal format with the same value,” and a footnote notes that different forms need not convert to the same internal format and value, raising the possibility that a C implementation that converted `1.575E1` and `1.575e1` to different values would conform to the standard.

Comment: Fortunately, the standard itself does not matter—it only matters how the standard is interpreted by people reading it.